# Choosing the cluster values in k means algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, k-means

I'm working on writing a k means algorithm that takes in a double[][] that stores locations and returning two clusters of locations.

I just have a really quick question: ***what is the best way to choose what the initial cluster values should be?***

I've tried randomizing the values but that doesn't always work well, and I can't find any good answers to this question online. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unless you absolutely have to use a standard k-means algorithm, you could look up the k-harmonic means algorithm. It uses a different performance function which is supposed to make it much less sensitive to the selection of initial cluster centers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One popular strategy that is usually more effective than random selection is to pick the first value at random, and then choose the second value by finding the farthest data point from the first selection.

The next value would then be chosen to be the furthest from both of the first two, and so on.

This is similar to the slightly more complex initialization algorithm [K-means++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B#Initialization_algorithm).